# How can I use data from PDF map?

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, tilemill, pdf, illustrator

I have a map over Sweden with plenty of data represented as circles of various sizes. The map is saved as PDF from Illustrator, fully editable.
I wonder if there is any way I could get these circles into Tilemill so that I can make a searchable georeferenced map? I don't know the projection but I would guess WGS84 or SWEREF99.

One way that comes to mind is to extrakt the geodata from a geotiff of Sweden (if I find one with the same projection), place PDF-map on top of the geotiff in Illustrator/Photoshop and then use gdal to insert the geodata again.

Any ideas if this is a good way, or if there are better methods?[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. Convert this pdf map as dxf format using "Adobe Illustrator"

2.Take some control points from Google earth in map area and mark same places in dxf file

then do spatial adjustment (Arcgis) with familiar software.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could do it with java.

1. Maybe you could do it with java
2. Search circles by colors.
3. Get coordinates of circles.
4. Match this coordinates with some third party like google.